# Ubuntu is very, very, very slow

Tags: 64-bit

I have installed Ubuntu and it is extremely slow. Typing this text now is extremely frustrating since every 4 - 3 words I type the computer freezes. I have a 3.2 GHz processor and 8 gb ram. My graphics card is:

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Barts PRO [ATI Radeon HD 6800 Series] [1002:6739]
Subsystem: Giga-byte Technology Device [1458:21f8].
```

I'm not running heavy programs on the computer.

Comment: Most often that's because of a hardware problem (something going bad or something that's bad and the kernel is trying to access it over and over again) or incompatibility. You may want to check your logs to see whether anything appears there.

Comment: I apologize for this but where do I find the log? I'm a fairly new user.

Comment: Ah! Most of logs are found under /var/log. The main file is called syslog. The boot process is saved in dmesg. These are text files, although a few logs are binary. In a console you can type `less /var/log/syslog` so you can go up and down. To go to the end, use the End key or Shift-G.

Comment: Nothing seems to be wrong. I installed Ubuntu to see if it would work on other computers I had and it did... whats up with this one?

Answer (score 0):

Something wrong on the installation like:
-There is not a swap partition
-You could have installed a 64bit on a 32bit computer or viceversa
-There could be a process (even if you don´t notice) that is try to run
-You are trying and imposible situation whith the installation, or have an error on it

You have to be more especific, give details of how do you install it

Answer (score 0):

I suggest tuning swappiness in sysctl.conf first, just to be sure it's not the disk being paged constantly. To do this, open a new Terminal (Dash > Terminal) and type:

```
sudo nano /etc/sysctl.conf
```

Then scroll to the bottom of the window and type in the following:

```
vm.swappiness=10
vm.vfs_cache_pressure=50
```

Also make sure you're using the latest proprietary drivers. You can get them from Dash > Additional Hardware.

If none of the above helps, I would suggest getting a copy of a Live environment (CD or USB) and running Gparted to check for disk errors.

Answer (score 0):

When I wonder what's running, I run `top` in a terminal. It will tell you what's running. If something's sucking that many cpu cycles, it will be at the top of the list. Gives you the process ID number you can use to kill the process if that's appropriate.